# How much constriction pressure would a naga have?

Tags: biology

One thing I don't see discussed often in regards to naga is how much constriction pressure their tails would have. Given their size, I'd imagine it'd be much more pressure than a green anaconda, which has the highest recorded constriction pressure at 90 pounds per square inch (and coincidentally is also the largest extant snake on the planet). Some back of the napkin math comparing muscle density comes out to about 200 psi for a naga, but that feels awfully little, given their size. Is this estimate accurate, or can it stand to be refined?

Comment: Cool question! To refine it: how big is your naga? Could you specify what variables (length? diameter?) you're basing your calculations on? Could you show your back-of-the-napkin calculations, so that other people who are better at math than I might be able to confirm or correct them?

Comment: 30 feet long, including the human portion, and about 50 inches in circumference at their widest point.

Comment: For refining the math, I assumed that the strength of a creature's muscles grow as a fraction of it's mass. Green Anacondas grow to about 15 feet on average, so I doubled that length and used the square cube law to find its new volume and used that as a ballpark for mass.

Comment: I don't remember what the exact ratio of muscle strength to body volume is, I think it was about 2/3s or something close, but as I recall correctly, I tripled 90 psi to get 270 and multiplied by that 2/3s to get 180, which I rounded up to 200.

Comment: very useful study if someone wants to do the math https://mehta.eeb.ucsc.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/BookChapter2007.pdf constriction pressure = 15.2 X diameter +16.41 X number of loops - 29.43

Comment: 50 inches circumference or 40 cm diameter while anacondas are closer to 30 cm diameter. Personally I would say keep it the same to keep it plausible maybe a 10% boost.. Because don't forget the square-cube law still plays an affect. It will be applying a stronger flex (pressure up) )over a wider body area(pressure down).

Comment: I am not sure about this 90PSI figure. In fact I cannot find any reputable-looking source for how strong is an anaconda.

Comment: Hey new user. You should edit the question to include the dimensions of the creature, and maybe edit the title too. You are essentially asking how hard can a snake THIS BIG squeese. The naga part is not important.

Comment: keep in mind snakes don't actually squeeze all that hard, the fact they keep it up for so long is what kills, they are effectively keeping you from inhaling thus causing you to suffocate. every time you exhale your body contracts and they squeeze a little tighter.  Its not crushing or anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

The naga's constriction pressure is not only due to its size, muscles, etc. Naga (at least in the conventional definition) are magical, and semi divine beings. As such, they are supernatural, not simply in the sense of being superhuman. As this stands, there is no way to give a biology or science based answer to this. A 10 foot Naga that is 20 feet wise could have a psi of 400, if it is empowered by magic/divinity. The hybrid nature could go both ways, in terms of strength. In some mythologies, pure bred monsters are stronger, but in others, being bred with a human makes the offspring stronger. Since it is magic, you get to decide whether you want it to be consistent or not. In other words, is magic A always magic A? Or does magic A sometimes follow the rules of Magic B?

So in short, since a Naga is a mythical, semidivine, magical being that does not follow any scientific biology, it is up to you to define how much psi the Naga can apply. The magical component makes it so that you have the freedom to establish your own rules.

Comment: Nagas don't like to get their hands dirty. Which is no problem because everyone knows even a baby Naga can cast spells like Captivate, Flame Wave, Greater Teleport, Summon Toddler, Captivate,  Tide of Wasps, Astral Form and Psychic Lance ten times per day each.  Some of the Ancient Nagas claimed to know forbidden spells like Stock Market Kaboom, Heightened Empowered Big Space Rock, and Delete Facebook.